# Module Laravel could not be found and loaded

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, lumen, codecept

Codecept is used for unit testing in my application, and accidentally, it stopped working and gave the following error when running unit tests:

```
In ModuleContainer.php line 80:

Module Laravel could not be found and loaded
```

Module Laravel is used in unit.suite.yml under 'enabled' section as follows:

```
 modules:
  enabled:
    - Asserts
    - \Helper\Unit
    - Db
    - Laravel
    - Cli
    - \Helper\ElasticsearchHelper
```

Composer json

```
  "require-dev": {
        "codeception/codeception": "^2.4",
         
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/"
    },
```

Is there any way to enable the Laravel module in Laravel. This application is developed using laravel Lumen.

Answer (score 0):

Module should be Lumen. Not Laravel in unit.suite.yml.

This would be the case when upgrading the Lumen API to the latest Laravel. Laravel no longer recommends that we to begin new projects with Lumen. Instead, Laravel recommends always beginning new projects with Laravel.